# What is the fastest way to duplicate google storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have one 10TB bucket and need to create it's copy as quickly as possible. What is the fastest and most effective way of doing this?

Comment: Did you look at the built-in Transfer Service? https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/

Comment: I tried this for S3 but never thought it could be able to copy from gs to gs. Thanks

Comment: Hope it helped. Have added as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you want to copy the bucket to another bucket in the same location and storage class, you could run gsutil rsync on a GCE instance:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -d -p gs://source-bucket gs://dest-bucket
```

If you want to copy across locations or storage classes the above command will still work, but it will take longer because in that case the data (not just metadata) need to be copied.

Either way, you should check the result status and re-run the rsync command if any errors occurred. (The rsync command will avoid re-copying objects that have already been copied.) You should repeat the rsync command until the bucket has successfully been fully copied.

Comment: Careful with the `-d` as it will delete files in `gs://dest-bucket` that don't exist in `gs://source-bucket`. Use `-n` for a dry run first. [source](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#be-careful-when-using--d-option).

Comment: You will need to drop the `-p` option If you get an error about "OWNER permission is required for preserving ACLs.".

Answer (score 14):

One simple way is to use Google's [Cloud Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/). It may also be the fastest, though I have not confirmed this.

Comment: Definitely, the easiest to do without the cli, [see their how-to guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets)

Comment: This was much faster than the solutions above.

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this easily with [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install).

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://source-bucket gs://duplicate-bucket
```

Are you copying within Google Cloud Storage to a bucket with the same location and storage class?  If so, this operation should be very fast.  If the buckets have different locations and/or storage classes, the operation will be slower (and more expensive), but this will still be the fastest way.

Comment: I upvoted Mike Schwartz's answer.  The command I suggested will be slightly faster because it doesn't have to fully enumerate all of the objects in the source bucket before beginning the copy.  However, if anything goes wrong during the operation (for example, you experience a transient network outage) then you'd need to start the copy over from the beginning.  Mike's command can also be re-run to incrementally synchronize the destination bucket the source bucket later on, after the source bucket's contents have changed.